# reRender via JS API

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I was wondering if there is any JS function in `jsf/richfaces` which does the same functionality as that of reRendering a component.

Also will the reRender work on any component which has `display:none` style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a4j:jsFunction with 'render' set. Then from javascript call the jsFunction and the render will be done. I think that render does not check the display style setting.

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="render" render="componentToRenderId"/>
</h:form>

<script>
  render();
</script>
```

MAG,
Milo van der Zee

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using RichFaces 3.x because you are using jsf-1.2. 
If so, you can use the  component as 'Milo vd Zee' showed but your attribute should be changed as "***reRender***" instead of "***render***".
For Richfaces 4.2 "***render***" attribute is ok.